# Travelling - Spain from France on 11 Feb

Tags: france, health, spain, flixbus

I will be traveling from Paris to Barcelona on Flixbus. I have an EU digital certificate and have completed two doses of vaccination. Do I need to undergo an antigen or RT PCR test?

Comment: Have you checked any of the official webpages? I don't know if Flixbus applies the internal French rules on international routes but if that is the case, the date you received the second dose will matter. If it's too old, you are not allowed to travel (and even a test won't get you and exception, unless you can justify that you are traveling for family or health reasons).

Comment: If you ended up taking the trip, it could be helpful to others if you answer this question with your experience

Answer (score 1):

As of 13 February 2022, you **don't** need an antigen or PCR test when traveling by road. Your **EU digital certificate is enough**.

Source: [Embassy of France in Spain - 2/ Entry to Spanish territory](https://es.ambafrance.org/Covid-19-a-savoir-pour-tout-deplacement-entre-la-France-et-l-Espagne#t2-Entree-sur-le-territoire-espagnol)